# In how many ways may a college president's wife invite two or more of eight faculty wives to a tea?

Tags: combinations

**Q.** In how many ways may a college president's wife invite two or more of eight faculty wives to a tea?

Since it is two or more , inviting one must be excluded . Therefore , the answer would be $\binom{8}{8}-\binom{8}{1}$ . Am I correct?

Comment: What do you mean by two or more?

Comment: You do realise your answer is negative?

Answer (score 0):

We need to compute $\sum_{n=2}^{8} {8\choose n} = \sum_{n=0}^{8} {8\choose n} - {8\choose 1} - {8\choose 0} = 2^8-9$

Answer (score 0):

You must know that the number of ways of choosing two people from $8$ is given by $\binom82$. Similarly, we can calculate the rest.

Hence, our answer is: $$P = \binom82 + \binom83 + \ldots + \binom88 = 2^8 - \binom81 - \binom80 = 2^8-9 = 247$$

Note that $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom {n}{i} = 2^n $$